Maximal width and the diameter of a convex figure
Suppose, one has a planar convex figure $\Omega$ with a smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. I want to find its diameter by using some algorithm which looks as follow: take some point $A_1\in\partial\Omega$, then take another point $A_2$ on the boundary again, after that, build up a line segment $A_1A_2$. Here comes the trick: to make up some segment longer than $A_1A_2$ one is to build a perpendicular from $A_2$ (or from $A_1$) and prolong it up to the intersection with the boundary of $\Omega$. Acting like that we make up a point $A_3$ and get a longer segment $A_1A_3$ (or $A_2A_3$ correspondingly). Then we repeat this iteration and there emerge points $A_n, n=4,5,6,\ldots$
My algorithm finds a local extremum of length of a segment lying inside the figure, but I need a global one.
My question is: how should one take the first two points? Should they be the points of maximal width?
By the way, diameter intersects the boundary of a figure with right angles! It might be quite handy in this problem.

Choose $n$ points on the boundary and use rotating calipers to find the diameter of the corresponding convex polygon. Choose $n$ large enough to get the accuracy you need.
There may be a way to improve the result with iteration, refining the partition of the boundary with more points near the pair that results in the longest diagonal from an initial approximation.
